# What fingers are supposed to be used to press function keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

All fast typing tutorials on the internet ([image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard%20finger%20layout&tbm=isch)) care only about keys that are below function keys. No one tells you what fingers to use to press those function keys.

Assuming you use all ten fingers and type without looking at the keyboard, what fingers are supposed to be used to press function (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>) keys?

Is there an official typing method to handle functions keys?

If not, I understand that it is probably left for the personal preference. But if someone figured out that it is most optimal (on qwerty keyboard) to press <kbd>f</kbd> key with you left index finger and <kbd>j</kbd> with your right index finger, then there is a chance someone came up with the most optimal finger mapping for the function keys as well.

Comment: Well, if anyone is interested, I settled on using left hand pinky through the index finger for F1-F4. The same goes for F5-F8. For F9-F12 I use right hand index through pinky.

Answer (score 2):

Function keys are not part of standard typing (but a later add-on for computer users), nor are they really standard and only used for special rare circumstances that do not occur in regular typing. So you are correct, it is personal preference.